# Is it possible to reuse sk_buff?

Tags: linux-device-driver, dma, zero-copy

On every received ethernet frame driver allocates new sk_buff buffer which is innefficient. Is it possible to allocate a bunch of sk_buffs during initialization and reuse those sk_buffs after high levels stops using it?

Comment: Imagine the case when the producer will be faster than consumer. What will you do?

Comment: 0andriy, I would use ring buffer for this.